# file uploader needed in joomla 3 component like template logo uploader

Tags: joomla, components

I am creating a component in joomla 3  and i need a image uploader for that component like template logo uploader (Show light box popup and image selection). I don't know how to do that kindly reply if anybody knows it

Answer (score 0):

The following address will present the view for selecting an image from media manager

```
http://yourdomain/administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&e_name=jform_articletext&asset=com_content&author=
```

so you can open it in any light box popup implementation

The page that opens it must include a

```
function jInsertEditorText( text, editor ){....}
```

This function will be called once the "Insert" button is selected.

I will provide a simple example of this implementation using all the functionality that is available by default in joomla3.

On a page of your component you may use the following code to include a button that shows a modal window of bootstarp (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" style="position:fixed;top:50px"class="btn" data-toggle="modal">show popup</a>
```

*(please don't pay much attention to the style attribute as it is there for testing purposes)*

If you simply want to do this from the console or js you can do

```
jQuery("body").append('<a href="#myModal" role="button" style="position:fixed;top:50px"class="btn" data-toggle="modal">show popup</a>');
```

then you may add an iframe with the url i mentioned above (the same approach is followed by joomla when you push "image" in article editor)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><iframe id="choose-image" src="http://joomla31.cloudaccess.net/administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&e_name=jform_articletext&asset=com_content&author="></iframe></div>
```

to execute from console or js dynamically,

```
jQuery("body").append('<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><iframe id="choose-image" src=""></iframe></div>');
jQuery('#choose-image').attr("src","http://joomla31.cloudaccess.net/administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&e_name=jform_articletext&asset=com_content&author=");
```

Then you may either provide a js function jInsertEditorText( text, editor ){....} in your page and handle the insert after selecting image on the popup.
Or simply provide a custom handling for the Insert button 
try calling following code from console or in script

```
Query("iframe#choose-image").load(function(){jQuery("#choose-image").contents().find(".btn.btn-primary:contains('Insert')").attr("onclick","").click(function(){alert(jQuery("#choose-image").contents().find("#f_url").val());});});
```

it basically removes the default onclick script and adds a custom handling of click by showing the selected image path on an alert dialog.

Comment: Hi thanks melc . sorry Can you explain it clearly.. also needed same preview cancel button.How to display it in form? instead of using normal file upload?

Comment: Edited answer by providing a step by step example. Please note that after the iframe is loaded by jQuery you can actually modify the whole view in any way you want i.e. remove/hide fields, change captions etc